# Multiple colors in TextField of Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-textinputlayout, android-compose-textfield

Is it possible to get different colors in a TextField of Jetpack Compose?

Something like with the `Text` composable with `AnnotatedString`, but TextField doesn't allow `AnnotatedString` as input value.

Image of normal Text composable with colors

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the **`VisualTransformation`** in the `TextField`.

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    visualTransformation = ColorsTransformation()
)
```

In the `VisualTransformation` you can use [**`AnnotatedString`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString) to display the text with multiple styles.

Something like:

```
class ColorsTransformation() : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        return TransformedText(
            buildAnnotatedStringWithColors(text.toString()), 
            OffsetMapping.Identity)
    }
}
```

with:

```
fun buildAnnotatedStringWithColors(text:String): AnnotatedString{
    val words: List<String> = text.split("\\s+".toRegex())// splits by whitespace
    val colors = listOf(Color.Red,Color.Black,Color.Yellow,Color.Blue)
    var count = 0

    val builder = AnnotatedString.Builder()
    for (word in words) {
        builder.withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = colors[count%4])) {
            append("$word ")
        }
        count ++
    }
    return builder.toAnnotatedString()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. <3

Comment: Is there a way to delete the entire styled word when a character is deleted. I have some styled text that is colored. Theser are @mentions names. Want to delete the entire names. Any idea what can de done?

Answer (score 0):

depending on *Gabriele Mariotti* answer, if you had trouble in inherit `VisualTransformation` class you can use `TransformedText` directly in the `TextField`.

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    visualTransformation = {
        TransformedText(
            buildAnnotatedStringWithColors(text),
            OffsetMapping.Identity
        )
    }
)


fun buildAnnotatedStringWithColors(text:String): AnnotatedString{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

TextField directly supports AnnotatedString if you use the version that uses TextFieldValue instead of plain strings (see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#TextField(androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material.TextFieldColors))).

The annotated string is contained inside the TextFieldValue, in the `annotatedString` property (see [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/input/TextFieldValue)), together with the selection and the composition ranges.

**UPDATE:** there is an [open bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135556699) that makes the TextField lose the formatting info as soon as it gets the focus, so don't use this approach just yet.